# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'texttable'

Tags: python, error-handling

Even after I have installed the module texttable, I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: By typing `!which python` in Jupyter notebook cell you can check if that is the right python environment you are using.
Sometimes Jupyter might be using different python installation than the one where you installed the module

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Jupyter, to ensure you are installing the module in the correct python environment, can you try below command in the next Jupyter cell?

```
!pip install texttable
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and install pip

Then install texttable calling `pip install texttable`

Comment: I have already used that command, it's showing requirment already satisfied while running in jupyter notebook, but when i try to run the code, it's showing no module error.